# pandas datetime to Unix

Tags: time-series, pandas

I need to convert a datetime.date(2007, 4, 30) to a Unix timestamp in pandas.

thank you.

my datable:

```
0     2007-04-30
1     2007-05-31
2     2007-06-30
3     2007-07-31
4     2007-08-31
Name: datetime, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4):

finally worked something out though I wonder if it is the best solution?

```
dt = pd.DatetimeIndex ( dt ).astype ( np.int64 )/1000000
```

cheers.

Comment: Please try my alternative, and mark it if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `view` method ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#from-timestamps-to-epoch)):

```
from pandas import Series
from datetime import date
df = Series([date(2007,4,30), date(2007,5,31), date(2007,6,30), date(2007,7,31), date(2007,8,31)], dtype='datetime64')
df.view('int64')
```

The output is:

```
0    1177891200000000000
1    1180569600000000000
2    1183161600000000000
3    1185840000000000000
4    1188518400000000000
dtype: int64
```

Comment: just say your answer - great.  Thank you.

Comment: note that the `view` method throws a TypeError if the Series is empty, while the `astype` method does not; just in case you might need to deal with that in your data

Answer (score 2):

These are the fastest two methods I've found, displayed with their respective runtimes. Results were averaged over 1000 iterations using a series with a length of about 30k.

`df['date'].view('int64')`

Avg. Runtime: 58us

`df['date'].astype(np.int64)`

Avg. Runtime: 98us

**Note 1:** Depending on the architecture of your machine (32-bit vs 64-bit), pandas and numpy may store times in different units. I've seen comments about behavior changing between versions.

**Note 2:** When dealing with large datasets, consider using unsigned integers since your times will always be positive. Also, you may not need nanosecond precision, in which case converting to seconds may allow further downcasting.